# HttpClient Get object object

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to display my json using httpclient but I have an error that I can't solve.

i have this error: **Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed**

thanks.

**json**

```
{
  "toto": [
    "titi",
    "tata"
  ],
"foo": [
    "foobar",
    "footix"
  ]
}
```

**ts.file**

```
get() {
    this.homeService.getAll().subscribe(result => {
      this.postArray = result;
      console.log(this.postArray);
    });
  }
```

**html**

```
<div*ngFor="let post of postArray">
        <span>{{post.libelle}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**interface**

```
export interface Ipost {
  toto:string[],
  foo:string[]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is self-explanatory. `*ngFor` only supports iterables whereas you're trying to iterate an object.

You could use the [`keyvalue`](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) pipe is such cases:

```html
<div*ngFor="let post of postArray | keyvalue">
  <h3>{{ postArray.key }}</h3>
  <span *ngFor="let item of postArray.value">{{ item }}</span>
</div>
```

For the example object in the question, the above would render the following

---

**toto**
titi
tata
**foo**
foobar
footix

---